# "Illegal reference to memory" in Verilog switch case

Tags: switch-statement, verilog, state-machine, synthesis

I am trying to write a Finite State Machine for an assignment. However, I don't understand what is wrong with my module code. I get the error:

> ERROR VCP5221 "Illegal reference to memory: st." "design.sv" 77  5

when I try to synthesize. I think I've either misunderstood how switch-case is used in Verilog or I've attempted to make an illegal assignment inside the switch-case but I don't know how to find it.

```
//Code here

module MooreFSM(
  input clk,
  input in,
  output out
);
  
  reg state[2:0];
  reg sel[2:0];
  reg o;
  assign out = o;
  
  initial begin
    state <= 3'b000;
    o <= 1'b0;
  end
  
  always@(negedge clk) begin
    state <= sel;
  end
  
  always@(posedge clk) begin
    case(state)
      3'b000: begin
        if(in == 1'b0) begin
          sel <= 3'b010;
          o <= 1'b0;
        end
        else if(in == 1'b1) begin
          sel <= 3'b001;
          o <= 1'b0;
        end
      end
      3'b001: begin
        if(in == 1'b0) begin
          sel <= 3'b000;
          o <= 1'b0;
        end
        else if(in == 1'b1) begin
          state <= 3'b011;
          o <= 1'b0;
        end
      end
      3'b010: begin
        if(in == 1'b0) begin
          sel <= 3'b100;
          o <= 1'b0;
        end
        else if(in == 1'b1) begin
          sel <= 3'b000;
          o <= 1'b0;
        end
      end
      3'b011: begin
        if(in == 1'b0) begin
          sel <= 3'b000;
          o <= 1'b1;
        end
        else if(in == 1'b1) begin
          sel <= 3'b011;
          o <= 1'b1;
        end
      end
      3'b100: begin
        if(in == 1'b0) begin
          sel <= 3'b100;
          o <= 1'b1;
        end
        else if(in == 1'b1) begin
          sel <= 3'b000;
          o <= 1'b1;
        end
      end
      default: begin
        sel <= 3'b000;
        o <= 1'b0;
      end
    endcase
  end
endmodule
```

Please help me identify the problem, or if I need to use a different method to synthesize a mux.

Answer (score 0):

I think when you put

```
else if(in == 1'b1) begin
  state <= 3'b011;
  o <= 1'b0;
end
```

you might have meant to write

```
else if(in == 1'b1) begin
  sel <= 3'b011;
  o <= 1'b0;
end
```

By putting `state` as something being assigned in just one case of this switch statement, you're implicitly asking for it to be latched back to in every other case, which conflicts with you explicitly making it a flop above.